# How to disable injection JavaScript into browsers?

Tags: antivirus, injection

I am using Kaspersky Antivirus and recently I've updated it to Kaspersky Total Security 16.0.0.614. When I checked my browsers I realized Kaspersky injects remote JavaScript into all my pages even secure ones. This version of KTS is keep injecting [main.js](https://ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js) every 2 millisecond on webpages, like this picture :

[image]

I research some related document specially [Kaspersky forum](http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t316466.html) and followed all the Instructions but none of them works such as turn Anti-banner off or disable URL Advisor.

I don't like to Uninstall Kaspersky, So now the question is:

1-What is this script?

2-How can I disable this injection? or block it by browsers?

Comment: Woah, I've not seen anything like that. Could you link the script?

Comment: I added it to question before.Check main.js inside the question.

Comment: @Gabriel yes, I tried to access it but got connection refused. Could you save it and link it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered on the vendor's support forum.

Comment: No, there is no answer in that topic. look at the last topic at the question. None of the solution works. I followed All the solution before I asked this question.

Comment: You need to include in your question the steps you took and the research you have performed to help answer your problem. The added details mean that we aren't wasting our time coming up with answers that you have already tried, and the added details can help us narrow in on an answer.

Comment: As for your first question, it is answered in the link I provided.

Comment: I installed Kaspersky Total Security, But this forum talk about Kaspersky internet security. I used KIS before I update to KTS and there was no problem with it. I checked All the solution but All of them not works for me. would you please give me the solution you are talking about, It could be I miss some thing? thank you.

Comment: @Malavos I saved the Script in new address. please check script file in this address. http://plnkr.co/edit/6wG5Pc3rXT2IoTKB76AZ?p=preview

Comment: @Gabriel I have made a preliminary checage. So, it seems that the main work as some kind of interface (someone said that in the topic as well) but there are direct consequences to this - this script can be easily be intercepted by others scripts. If you check it, it runs though the dom of the page, has some forbidden tags, virtual keyboard implementation, and a lot of event listener. It's all "Legal" and won't interfer with your personal data. But it seems really bulky, so it can slow very much your page loading and navigation.

Comment: @Malavos Thanks for your comment. But the problem is this injection make my page loading very slow and my browser console will crash after a minute. really need some solution to block this injection. It's made me worry When I read this blog : http://geektimes.ru/post/259750/

Comment: Have you tried something like noscript? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?hl=en this is for chrome.

Comment: @Gabriel I translated that page, yes, looks troublesome, but I think there's nothing there that can directly affect your privacy - but script injection is not even in the standards. The script can help, but it's too much for that.

Comment: Yes really it's too much . I could block this script by `ScriptSafe` in the Google Chrome. I need to add some thing like that to all my browsers.

Comment: @schroeder Same question asked 2 months after my question and solved my problem. what is the different between this question and mine. I don't get it why my question closed? http://superuser.com/questions/981959/how-to-disable-kaspersky-antivirus-javascript-injection

Comment: @Gabriel that question is on a totally different site .... That site deals with user applications. This site deals with information security issues. You have an application problem, not a security problem. Also, your original question was answered by the vendor's site and you did not explain that you had tried those options. All of these things combined meant that it is off-topic.

Comment: hey it has simple solution use this lines in hosts file.

127.0.0.1   gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com